# Optimization of matrix multiplication in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, optimization

I'm currently trying to do some work on a neural network class in visual basic. My main drag at the moment is the multiplication of the matrices is *so* slow! Here's the code I use right now;

```
   Public Function MultiplyMatricesParallel(ByVal matA As Double()(), ByVal matB As Double()()) As Double()()
    Dim matACols As Integer = matA(0).GetLength(0)
    Dim matBCols As Integer = matB(0).GetLength(0)
    Dim matARows As Integer = matA.GetLength(0)
    Dim result(matARows - 1)() As Double
    For i = 0 To matARows - 1
        ReDim result(i)(matBCols - 1)
    Next
    Dim tempMat()() As Double = MatrixTranspose(matB)
    Parallel.For(0, matARows, Sub(i)
                                  For j As Integer = 0 To matBCols - 1
                                      Dim temp As Double = 0
                                      Dim maA() As Double = matA(i)
                                      Dim maB() As Double = tempMat(j)
                                      For k As Integer = 0 To matACols - 1
                                          temp += maA(k) * maB(k)
                                      Next
                                      result(i)(j) += temp
                                  Next
                              End Sub)
    Return result
End Function
```

I just jagged arrays as they are quicker in vb than rectangular arrays. Of course they really are rectangular otherwise the matrix multiplication wouldn't work (or make sense). Any advice/help would be appreciated, for reference the matrix size can change but it's currently around 7,000 x 2,000 at the maximum.

Comment: .Net has a [pre-optimized matrix type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix(v=vs.110).aspx) built in.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks, I've seen this before but it always looked a bit bulky and cumbersome (how would I dynamically initialise the matrix for example?).

Comment: Is this really a dense matrix? Shouldn't it be sparse? It might help to maintain the data in a flat array rather than a jagged one.

Comment: It really is a dense matrix (values in every single place). By flat array do you mean something like dim m(14000) as double?